# Why is my scope not binding to 'this'?

Tags: typescript, angularjs-directive, binding

I've been trying to get started with TypeScript combined with Angular 1.6.4, and so far things are going well.

I've gotten stuck on Directives, using 'scope' and 'this'. It seems no matter how I register my directive, the values under 'this' are never updated.

```
class TileBoxDir implements ng.IDirective {
    public templateUrl = "App/_shared/elements/tileBox/tileBoxView.html";
    public controller = TileBoxDir;
    public scope = {
        tileList: '='
    }
    public link: (scope, elem, attr) => void;

    public tileList: ITile[];

    static $inject = [];
    constructor() {
        TileBoxDir.prototype.link = (scope, elem, attr) => {
            console.log(this.tileList);
            console.log(scope.tileList);
        }
    }

    static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = () => new TileBoxDir();
        directive.$inject = [];
        return directive;
    }
}

angular.module('app').directive('tileBox', TileBoxDir.factory());
```

In the constructor, the first console.log(...) always returns undefined, where the second one correctly logs the value I'm passing from the above controller.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You never assign a value to tileList in your TileBoxDir constructor. Thus it is normal that it always is undefined.

If you want `this.tileList` to contain the values of `scope.tileList` you have to add `this.tileList = scope.tileList` before logging.

Comment: I understand that, but is there no way to map these 2 together automatically?

Comment: Why would these be mapped? this represents the current class and scope isn't. Thus they won't be mapped.

Comment: I have to use the Class properties to properly set the types. If I just use scope directly, all these properties are marked as being 'any', which completely negates the point of using TypeScript. So I want to map them automatically, so I don't have to manually add every property in the link function.

Regardless of if they SHOULD be mapped automatically, can it be done?